# How to show the quick replies vertically in dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'm working with dialogflow quick replies and i want to show the options to the user vertically. What i mean is, by default, the user will see the options side by side and they have to scroll horizontally to see the other options. The user sees something like this:

Option1 Option2 Option3 Option4.

However, i want to display it vertically:

Option1

Option2

Option3

Option4

I read the dialogflow documentation but i couldnt find anything useful. I also tried "\n" that doesnt work either. This is what i have currently

```
    agent.add(new Suggestion("Option1"));
    agent.add(new Suggestion("Option2"));
    agent.add(new Suggestion("Option3"));
    agent.add(new Suggestion("Option4"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally suggestions are for Google Assistant and Fb Messenger.

**No way you can do this in any of the supported platforms.**

**You have to manage this on your front end side i.e your custom implementation of Dialogflow chat widget.**